# TCL - Convert Hexadecimal number to ASCII string

Tags: tcl

I'm very new to the whole world of scripting, and I am getting confused by TCL. So really I have a very basic question.

I have a proc function, that returns me a number, ie 0x6C or 6C

How do I display this number as the letter 'l'?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using [`format`](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/format.htm) with the `%c` specifier.

Example `tclsh` session:

```
% set num 0x6C
0x6C
% format %c $num
l
```

Comment: `binary format c $num` is also a possibility; it depends on whether one is logically producing characters or bytes. (Can the number be greater than 255?)